# Welcome to public beta!

Tags: discussion

As you may have noticed from the [Beta](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) badge being awarded, [privilege thresholds](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) being adjusted, and the [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence) status being updated, **we are now in public beta**!

This is a really special moment because, though we weren't the first to try, we were the first group to succeed in getting an AI-related Stack Exchange site off the ground. I'd like to thank the Stack Exchange team for being willing to try this again and for providing the advice and adjustments needed to keep us on track. Also, thanks to [all our users](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) who have been asking questions, posting answers, and building consensus on meta.

I would be interested to see what notes the community team has on our progress (as [was shared on another fairly new site](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/199)). Even if we were a little shaky at times, evidently we're doing well now!

Comment: Especially since [AI was the example of 'didn't make it out of private beta'](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/).

Comment: Hello and nice opening, this is really a big day to be considered a flash light of an unmissable and indispensable section for SE as AI, this is regarded a triumph very long awaited for !